# Malformed form-data Body for HTTP POST Request in Swift?

Tags: swift, facebook, http, post, whatsapp

I'm writing a HTTP POST request for uploading media (images here) to WhatsApp via the Facebook Graph API, formatted as follows in their documentation:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/media' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -F 'file=@/local/path/file.jpg;type=image/jpeg' 
  -F 'messaging_product=whatsapp'
```

I've got the information right, because it works when structuring the request from Postman, and keeping the body as form-data.

Here's the raw log from Postman for the successful request (I've removed the access token, the boundary string and the binaries for the image):

```
POST /v13.0/111101394989431/media HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d84bb595-a5a5-4f42-b286-46dfef5828e5
Host: graph.facebook.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<boundary-string>
Content-Length: 65306
--<boundary-string>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messaging_product"

whatsapp
--<boundary-string>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="gm.jpeg"

<gm.jpeg>
--<boundary-string>--
```

Here's my networking code in Swift, commented for your benefit. Please check out the createBody method (at bottom), which is likely the source of the poorly formatted HTTP body and thus 400 error.

```
//
//  WhatsappMediaAPIClient.swift
//  SnapShare
//
//  Created by Faraz Malik on 04/07/2022.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

enum WhatsappImageError: Error {
    case requestFailed
    case responseUnsuccessful(statusCode: Int)
    case jsonParsingFailure
    case invalidURL
}

class WhatsappImageAPIClient {
    private let whatsappPhoneID = "<phone-ID>"
    
    // returns the base url string with the phone ID attached, when accessed
    private lazy var baseUrlString: String = {
        return "https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/\(whatsappPhoneID)/media"
    }()
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let session: URLSession
    
    init(withConfiguration configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = .default) {
        self.session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    }
    
    // MARK: Typealiases
    
    typealias WhatsappImageCompletionHandler = (WhatsappImage?, Error?) -> Void
    
    
    // MARK: Post Whatsapp Image
    // called to upload image to WhatsApp via Facebook Graph API
    // calls escaping completion handler to pass up data or error appropriately.
    public func postWhatsappImage(withAccessToken accessToken: String, imageData: Data, completionHandler completion: @escaping WhatsappImageCompletionHandler) {
        
        // creates URL from URL string
        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrlString) else {
            completion(nil, WhatsappImageError.invalidURL)
            return
        }
        
        // gets a boundary string to work with for this request
        let boundaryString = getBoundaryString()
        
        // creates a request
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        // adds access token and content type as fields in the header
        request.addValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundaryString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        // required parameter for form-data in body
        let parameters = ["messaging_product": "whatsapp", "type": "image/jpeg"]
        
        // gets and assigns body, formatted to form-data with parameters and image data
        let requestData = createBody(withParameters: parameters, imageData: imageData, boundaryString: boundaryString)
        request.httpBody = requestData
        
        // sends request asynchronously (i.e. background)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // if we got a response
                if let data = data {
                    // if we can cast response as HTTPURLResponse
                    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                        completion(nil, WhatsappImageError.requestFailed)
                        return
                    }
                    
                    // if it's ok
                    if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                        do {
                            // try to decode it
                            let whatsappImageID = try self.decoder.decode(WhatsappImage.self, from: data)
                            // pass up to completion handler
                            completion(whatsappImageID, nil)
                        } catch {
                            // pass up to completion handler
                            completion(nil, WhatsappImageError.jsonParsingFailure)
                        }
                    } else if httpResponse.statusCode == 400 {
                        // print message for inspection
                        print("\n\n\n\n")
                        print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))
                        print("\n\n\n\n")
                        // pass up to completion handler
                        completion(nil, WhatsappImageError.responseUnsuccessful(statusCode: httpResponse.statusCode))
                    } else {
                        // pass up to completion handler
                        completion(nil, WhatsappImageError.responseUnsuccessful(statusCode: httpResponse.statusCode))
                    }
                    
                } else if let error = error {
                    // pass up error
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
    
    // creates body data (error could very well lie here because 400 bad request means body is malformed)
    // please give this a look (image is always jpeg)
    private func createBody(withParameters parameters: [String: String], imageData: Data, boundaryString: String) -> Data {
        
        let body = NSMutableData()
        let boundaryPrefix = "--\(boundaryString)\r\n"
        let filename = "upload.jpg"
                
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append(boundaryPrefix.data(using: .utf8)!)
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        }
        
        body.append(boundaryPrefix.data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append(imageData)
        body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        body.append("--".appending(boundaryString.appending("--\r\n")).data(using: .utf8)!)
        
        return body as Data
    }
    
    private func getBoundaryString() -> String {
        let boundary = "\(UUID().uuidString)"
        return boundary
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can spot what is going wrong, because I've been at this for 2 days and I can't figure out what I'm doing differently when sending the POST request from Swift compared to Postman - the difference that's making it fail.

Comment: `"type": "image/jpeg"` doesn't appear in the Postman code. Unrelated: But don't use `NSMutableData` use `Data`. And you can do `Data(aString.utf8)` instead of `aString.data(using: .utf8)!` Did you try generate Swift code from Postman to maybe spot a difference with your code? And `let boundary = "\(UUID().uuidString)"` can just be `let boundary = "UUID().uuidString`

Comment: Thanks for the message, I didn't know you could generate code from Postman (very useful), I'll try that now, thanks.

Comment: Swift code from POSTMAN is not very "Swifty" (don't copy/paste as such, if not just for testing purpose), but it can help you spot a difference that leads to a mistake.